# how to query get value without id

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to get the value of the column regardless of the id of the table, because I want to use `GROUP BY` to concatenate them

**from the table :**

| id_child | id_master | test1 | test2 | test3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 8 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 9 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

Expected result:

| id_master | test1 | test2 | test3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

My query :

```
SELECT
  cd.id_cutting_detail,
  CD.id_cutting,
  IF(cd.outermold_barcode IS NULL, '0', '1') AS `outer`,
  IF(cd.midmold_barcode IS NULL, '0', '1') AS `mid`,
  IF(cd.linningmold_barcode IS NULL, '0', '1') AS `linning`
FROM
  cutting_detail cd
GROUP BY
  cd.id_cutting
```

This is what current query generates:

| id_master | test1 | test2 | test3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: You already answered your own question; use `GROUP BY`. Please show your attempt using `GROUP BY` and demonstrate in what specific way it didn't work. Then we can help you fix that code.

Comment: @NicoHaase :
I've written my sql query above and the results I get are not what I want

Comment: @MatBailie : I've written my sql query above and the results I get are not what I want

Comment: Why are you selecting the first column? Your original question implies you don't want it?

Comment: The table and the query don't have anything in common.

Comment: @MatBailie : let's look at the table there are 2 ids, namely `id_child` and `id_master`, and this is the table_child, not the table_master.. I don't need the `id_child`, but I need the `id_master`

Comment: @FaNo_FN : what I wrote above is an example of a similar table. because the Complaining table is Too Long to display.. 
OK, I will write a query that matches the table above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  id_cutting,
  `outer`, 
  `mid`,
  `lining`
(
  SELECT
    cd.id_cutting,
    IF(cd.outermold_barcode IS NULL, '0', '1') AS `outer`,
    IF(cd.midmold_barcode IS NULL, '0', '1') AS `mid`,
    IF(cd.linningmold_barcode IS NULL, '0', '1') AS `linning`
  FROM
    cutting_detail cd
)
  AS nulls_checked
GROUP BY
  id_cutting,
  `outer`, 
  `mid`,
  `lining`
```

Or possibly...

```
  SELECT
    cd.id_cutting,
    MAX(IF(cd.outermold_barcode IS NULL, '0', '1')) AS `outer`,
    MAX(IF(cd.midmold_barcode IS NULL, '0', '1')) AS `mid`,
    MAX(IF(cd.linningmold_barcode IS NULL, '0', '1') ) AS `linning`
  FROM
    cutting_detail cd
  GROUP BY
    cd.id_cutting
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id_master
     , MAX(test1) test1
     , MAX(test2) test2
     , MAX(test3) test3
  FROM the_table
 GROUP
    BY id_master
```